How to configure tanstack router, using feature based folder structure
I am switching from react router to tanstack router.
Filebased routing is the goal, along with the usage of this folder structure:
src/
  main.ts
  pages/
    __root.tsx
    home/
      index.ts
      Home.tsx
      Home.styled.ts

BTW: I renamed the routes folder to pages and changed the configuration to make this work:
"routesDirectory": "./src/pages"

Inside the index.ts file for each page Component I register the route using the following lines:
import { createFileRoute } from '@tanstack/react-router'
import { Home } from './Home.tsx'

export const Route = createFileRoute('/home/')({
  component: Home,
})

export default Home

In the above folder structure I received the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '.../src/pages/home/Home.tsx' doesn't provide an export named: 'Route'

I don't want the page Component file (Home.tsx) to be factored in for routing since I am handling this inside the index.ts file.

Current Solution
... that I am not satisfied with is to prefix the Home.tsx file so it looks like this: -Home.tsx (adding a minus)
This way this file is ignored.
Is there a better way to configure this using the tsr.config.json?
I can't figure it out.
